# When should I escape urls?

Tags: ruby, url, uri

I have a URL and escaped it using:

```
url = "http://ec4.images-xxx.com/images/I/41-%2B6wMiewL._SL135_.jpg"
url = URI.escape(url)
puts url => "http://ec4.images-xxx.com/images/I/41-%252B6wMiewL._SL135_.jpg"
```

From the result I can see that URI escaped the previously escaped `%2B` again which became `%252B`, which is not correct.

I want to know how to make sure when one URL should be escaped. Or, is there a smart method that knows when to escape and when not to escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first string is already properly URI encoded, so when you try to re-encode it, the URI.escape method is encoding the '%' with '%25' (URI encoding for '+').

If you're really not sure whether your string has been URI encoded or not, you could try to decode it first, and compare it with the original. If they're the same, then it hasn't been encoded.

Comment: thank you for your solution on how to check one string is escaped or not. However if i checked that one string is not escaped, so i will use URI.escape to process it, but i found that URI.escape("+") doesn't have effect on escape for "+" to "%2B". why?

Comment: after read another post and know that + is part of path character and even though escape can not make "+" into "%2B", it works well. thank you.

Comment: You're right, but when you issue URI.decode('%2B') you get "+". But as you've said, the general principal is sound.

Comment: `%25` is URI encoding for `%`, not `+`. This makes perfect sense, since `%252B` decodes into `%2B` which decodes into `+`.